# how to i change child to another widget with drawer list tile

Tags: flutter

i can't use my child with drawer list tiles, this is my home admin code. I want to change my child :_widgetOptions[_selectedIndex] to another screen, so that the screen on the child changes according to the drawer list tile , im stuck in this code, i try it code and unexpected

```
class HomeAdminScreens extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeAdminScreens({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeAdminScreens> createState() => _HomeAdminScreensState();
}

class _HomeAdminScreensState extends State<HomeAdminScreens> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final brightness = theme.brightness;
    final textColor =
        brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.black : Colors.white;

    List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      DashboardScreen(),
      TransaksiScreen(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
              Expanded(
                child: SideMenu(
                  textColor: textColor,
                  onSelected: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            Expanded(flex: 5, child: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.svgSrc,
    required this.press,
    required this.textColor,
  });

  final String title, svgSrc;
  final Color textColor;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: press,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(svgSrc),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what I want to change on the dashboard screen, help me for this code

```
class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenu(
      {super.key, required this.textColor, required this.onSelected});

  final Color textColor;
  final ValueChanged<int> onSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/laundry.png",
                height: 80,
                width: 80,
              ),
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Dashboard",
              svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_dashboard.svg",
              press: () {
                onSelected(0);
              },
              textColor: textColor,
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Transaksi",
              svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_tran.svg",
              press: () {
                onSelected(1);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              textColor: textColor,
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Riwayat Transaksi",
              svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_task.svg",
              press: () {},
              textColor: textColor,
            ),
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Setting",
              svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_setting.svg",
              press: () {},
              textColor: textColor,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Scaffold( drawer: SideMenu (), body: _widgetOptions [_selectedIndex] )) 2. then change page according to DrawerItem ->onSelect()